# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). why cant i use a normal function

Tags: python, pandas

question: calculate the tip percentage and print `Generous` if tip >0.25 otherwise print `not generous`

if i am using lambda function its working fine that why not with a normal function call. i have attached the dataset i'm working with.

[image]

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0AFo.png)

function:

```
def tip_cal(total_bill, tip):
    if tip/total_bill > 0.25:
        return "Generous"
    else:
        return "fair"
```

function call:

```
df[['total_bill', 'tip']].apply(tip_cal(df['total_bill'], df['tip']), axis=1)
```

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Comment: I don't think the duplicate fully explains the issue in your case - the problem happens when you try to use `if`, but are passing the _entire column vector_ to `tip_calc` _once_ an then trying to pass that value to `.apply()`, rather than the individual row values - really you want to do one or the other, such as `numpy.where(df['tip'] / df['total_bill'] > 0.25, "Generous", "Fair")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening before the function is even applied. `tip_cal(df['total_bill'], df['tip'])` calls the function with the whole columns, not the individual values. So you'll need to rework your approach.

I'd use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of applying a function.

Comment: @ti7 It wasn't a duplicate... same error, different situation